# Finding PMF of C by given expected value

Tags: probability

Suppose that a cellular phone costs 20 \$ per month with 30 minutes of use included and that
each additional minute of use costs 0.50 $. If the number of minutes you use the phone in a
month is a geometric random variable M with expected value `E[M] = 1/p = 30 minutes`, what is
the `PMF of C`, the cost of the phone for one month?

I think `E[M]= 1/p` is referred Geometric RV. so `p=1/30` (this is how far i can go,)
how i can find `PMF of C` ?

Comment: MathJax hint: to avoid messing up the formatting, use \\\$ for a dollar sign, not just \$.

Comment: You know the PMF of M (its a geometric random variable with a certain mean). Find the function C(M). That is, the cost for the month given the number of minutes used. Then you have a function C of the random variable M.

Comment: PMF of M is 1/30 ? And that 20$ per month makes this question more complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If the number $M$ of minutes you use the phone is less or equal to $30$ then your cost is equal to the fixed cost, hence $$P(C=20)=P(M\le 30)$$ Now, for every additional minute of use above $30$ your cost increases about $0.5\$$. Thus $$P(C=20+0.5k)=P(M=30+k)$$ for $k=1, 2, 3, \ldots$ Since $M$ is geometrically distributed with parameter $p=1/30$ you know that $$P(M=n)=\left(\dfrac{1}{30}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{30}\right)^{n-1}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.